# Promise all in map then comes first

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm having trouble refactoring the following code. I can't seem to get a then() where all to the promises have resolved.  I make a db query, the do three async calls that return promises each. in this code my totally done comes first

```
const writeAll = (mongo) => {
  return new Promise((resolve,rej) => {
    mongo.connect(url, function(err, client) {
      const db = client.db(dbName);
      db.collection('table').find({}).toArray(function(err, res) {  
        let all = Promise.all(res.map(x => { 
          writeA(x)
          writeB(p)
          writeC(x, db)
        }))
        .then(data => console.log(data, "done here"))
        client.close();
        resolve(all)
      });
    });
  })
}

writeAll(mongo).then( data => console.log("Totally done"))
```

Comment: Since your `map` callback doesn’t return anything, there’s no asynchronous function for `Promise.all` to resolve. It just immediately resolves with `[undefined, undefined, `…`]`.

Comment: @Xufox ok so now I am returning an array of promises, nothing has changed.

Comment: For me its weird, I can't even see how "Totally done" is logged. because you are not using resolve anywhere within the returned Promise at line 2.

Comment: What `writeA` `writeB` and `writeC` functions return? If promises, do you want to wait for the resolve of the 3 writes for each `res` element? If yes, you have to do `Promise.all(res.reduce((prev, x) => { return prev.concat([writeA(x), writeB(p), writeC(x,db)])}, [])).then(data => { client.close(); resolve(data)})`

Comment: @diouze not for each three of the iteration, but I need to know when every promise in the map is done.

Comment: What promise? writeA, writeB or writeC?

Answer (score 0):

I had to reformat a little to fix compile errors, but...

a) returning a value from the promise.all's .then clause supplies a value for the returned promise to be fulfilled with (missing in the OP),

b) resolving the returned promise with the promise.all's promise chain prevents the returned promise from staying pending (missing in the OP)

c) Note `res.map` function does not return a value of any kind. It needs to return a promise, or the logic needs redesigning!

```
const writeAll = (mongo) =>
{
    return new Promise((resolve,rej) =>
    {
        mongo.connect(url, function(err, client)
        {
            const db = client.db(dbName);
            db.collection('table').find({}).toArray(function(err, res)
            {  
                resolve( Promise.all(res.map(x =>
                { 
                    writeA(x)
                    writeB(p)
                    writeC(x, db)
                    // RETURN value needed!
                }))              // res.map, Promise.all(....)
                .then(data => {
                      console.log(data, "done here");
                      client.close();
                      return data;
                }));           //  resolve, then(...);
            });                // toArray(...);
        });                    // mongo.connect
    });                        // new Promise(...)
};                             // const assign
```

Comment: I think it should be `return writeC(x, db)`, as pointed out by @Xufox